# How do I read from a redelivery queue in a batch way?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I am using ActiveMQ classic as a queue manager. My message consumer (@JmsListener using Spring) writes to MongoDB. If MongoDB is unavailable, then it sends the message to a different queue, lets call it a redelivery queue.

So, imagine after mongoDB been down for many hours, its finally up. What is the best way to now read the message from this redelivery queue?

I am thinking if there is a possibility to do this by creating a batch job that runs once a day? If so, what are the options that can be used to create a job like that or if there are any other better options available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "batch" mode for JMS. A JMS consumer can only receive one message at a time. Typically the best way boost message throughput to deal with lots of messages is by increasing the number of consumers. This should be fairly simple to do with a Spring `JmsListener` using the [`concurrency`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html#concurrency--) setting.

You can, of course, use something like `cron` to schedule a job to deal with these messages or you use something like the [Quartz Job Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) instead.

It's really impossible to give you the "best" way to deal with your situation on Stack Overflow. There are simply too many unknown variables.